# Isolation level of @Transactional method is read_committed and sometimes serializable. It should be always read_committed

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, azure-cosmosdb

Some time ago, I started getting weird errors from our production database:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
  Detail: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict in checking.
  Hint: The transaction might succeed if retried
```

This was confusing because those statements should have been executed in the `default` isolation level, `read_committed.`

I tested it on local Postgres, and everything seems OK. The isolation level was always `read_committed.` So, I enabled debug logging on the production CosmosDB. To my surprise, the isolation level for some statements executed in the same method annotated with `@Transactional` was sometimes `serializable` and sometimes `read_committed`.

For some logic, we use the `serializable` level, so it looks like it might be kept for a connection, which is reused later. Not sure if this is possible.

Before, we were using "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" with PgBouncer without HikariCP. So, I tried to switch back to HikarCP. After the switch, the total amount of executions with a `serializable` level was dramatically reduced, but it still happens occasionally.

This is how I log the isolation level in one frequently used method:

```
  @Async
  @Transactional
  fun updateLastUsedAsync(apiKey: ApiKey) {
      logTransactionIsolation()
      updateLastUsed(apiKey)
  }
```

```
  private fun logTransactionIsolation() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled) {
      val isolationLevel = entityManager.createNativeQuery("show transaction_isolation")
        .singleResult as String
      logger.debug("Transaction isolation level: $isolationLevel")
    }
  }
```

The output looked like this:

```
Transaction isolation level: serializable
Transaction isolation level: serializable
Transaction isolation level: serializable
Transaction isolation level: read_committed
Transaction isolation level: read_committed
Transaction isolation level: serializable
```

What could be the reason? Can it be some bug in the CosmosDB, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I am not sure if the switch to HikariCP really made a difference. Now it looks like it is related to user activities in the spring boot app. Sometimes it logs more unexpected serialization erros, sometimes less.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input, expected output and your code.

Comment: How are you setting the isolation level? As you state you are using `serializable` from some operations. You shouldn't be using `DriverManagerDataSource` in production as it isn't a connection pool and creates a new connection when needed. You are also using JPA, so I wonder how you are using things, feels like you are messing around with connections yourself where you shouldn't.

Comment: In most cases we are not explicitly setting the isolation level. Since the default for Postgres is read committed, we are OK with that. But when we do, we use `TransactionTemplate` or `@Transactional` annotation. I don't think we touch connections manually. 



Well, we used `DriverManagerDataSource `, since we use PgBouncer and we had some issues with HikariCP, which is now resolved, so we switched back.

Comment: But even if I messed with connections, how can this happen? Connection is disposed after transaction, right? Or can it happen that the new transaction inherits the isolation level from before somehow?